# How to to combine rows where atleast one column has duplicate data in mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to merge rows in mysql database if a key column has the same data for multiple rows. I just can't figure out a way to do this.

Here is the scenario:

```
clm0 clm1 clm2 clm3
 1    aa   ab   ad
 2    cb   ac   af
 3    aa   ab   xx
 4    cb   ac   yy
```

Here the column I want to check is `clm2`. If `clm2` is common for any rows, I would like to merge the rows. First row doesn't matter. So it would become this:

```
 clm0 clm1 clm2  clm3
  1    aa   ab  ad, xx
  2    cb   ac  af, yy
```

So can anyone please help me out in this? I am trying to achieve this in python just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat`:

```
select min(clm0), 
       clm1,
       clm2,
       group_concat(clm3)
from yourtable
group by clm1, clm2
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e7643/1)

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about this?